# knockout afterRender not executing

Tags: knockout.js

I am rendering a template using `ko.renderTemplate` method. After the template is rendered, I want to display google charts for which I am using the code below:

```
return ko.renderTemplate("container-graph", config,
                         {
                             afterRender: function (renderedElement) {
                                              //code to display google charts
                                          }
                         });
```

Below is the html that gets rendered. I want to display google charts inside the second div.

```
<div data-bind="attr: { id: id }, with: graph">
     <div data-bind="attr: { id: chartID}"></div>
</div>
```

`afterRender` never gets fired and so no charts are displayed.

Apart from `afterRender`, is there any other way with which I can display charts after the template is rendered ?

Comment: It would help if you edit the question and add a [small repro](http://sscce.org) in the question (possibly backed by a jsfiddle).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting things mixed up.

renderTemplate is a method you can call to render templates directly from code rather than rendering them from a template binding.  It has the following parameters:

1. Name of the template
2. ViewModel to bind to the template
3. Configuration Options
4. What DOM element to put the template in
5. The rendering mode (such as "replaceNode")

The parameters you're using to call renderTemplate don't make sense at all.

Perhaps you can try this instead:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { id: id }, with: graph">
  <div data-bind="attr: { id: chartID}, template: { name: "myGraphTemplate",
                        data: $data,
                        afterRender: thingToDoAfterRendering }"></div>
</div>

<script id="myGraphTemplate" type="text/html">
  <!-- Template goes here -->
</script>
```

With this on your viewmodel:

```
vm = {
  id: ko.observable(),

  graph: {
    chartId: ko.observable(),
    thingToDoAfterRendering: function(renderedElement) {
      // Code to display google charts
    }
  }

}
```

This answer is written with a lot of assumptions and guesses about how your code and markup are structured.  If this doesn't answer your question, you'll need to fill in a lot of missing information, including:

1. What does your viewmodel look like?  Be sure to include the function that calls renderTemplate (or is that part of a custom binding?)
2. What does your template look like?

For more information on renderTemplate, see:

- http://aboutcode.net/2012/11/15/twitter-bootstrap-modals-and-knockoutjs.html
- http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/knockout-js-pro-tips-working-with-templates/

Also be sure to review the template binding documentation:

- http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html